# JMeter embedded resources being downloaded when disabled

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

I have recorded a simple get/post test using the Blazemeter chrome plugin and am tweaking it in JMeter to be ready to use. However, the test fails because one of the embedded resources fails to load, which if it was correct, would be understandable.

I don't know if I am not understanding what I am seeing in the `View Results Tree` listener but I have some questions:

1. I don't need to download embedded resources but even though the box is NOT ticked on the http requests, they are still shown as downloaded. However, for the GET, these are dowloaded successfully.
2. I think that the post is failing and the same page is being returned by the server but when it comes to reloading the embedded resources, they all succeed except for one to fonts.googleapis.com, even though the same request always works for the get request

The failure is always the same each time I run it. Always, the embedded resources download correctly with GET and always that single 12th request to google fails with a 400.

Please can someone advise how to 1) Actually stop embedded resources from being downloaded and 2) work out how to debug why a second request to the same resource always fails even though it is simply an embedded font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en) adds [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) configuration element which populates the values for all the HTTP Request samplers in its [scope](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules). So if you don't want to download embedded resources (although it's not recommended) you need to open "Advanced" tab of the **Defaults** configuration element and untick the box there

   [image]
2. There is a [special property](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous) which controls whether a problem with fetching an embedded resource is treated as failure or not, if you would like to download embedded resources but at the same time to ignore failures you can add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
   ```

   upon JMeter restart problems with embedded resources won't fail the parent HTTP Request sampler. See [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) user manual chapter for more details if needed.

Comment: Perfect! In some cases we would want to download embedded resources as part of the test but in this case we just want to stress the servers to find out where they start struggling! Thanks.